# how to play mp4 video local file in the html?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I am trying to build a video player in website where i want to play the local video defaultly when page first loads without choosing it from the file picker. Where path of the video is known I tried the following code where i am able to play the audio not video. Please help me with this thanks

```
  <video controls autoplay>
  <source src="small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
```

here the small.mp4 video is stored in the same folder of the html file.

Comment: Browsers are not allowed to load local source, you need to run it from server. Are you running it from server?

Comment: i am using the flask framework to run the website locally

Comment: I think you will have to create a blob with JS

Comment: Can you specify how to create blob for my query?

Answer (score 4):

```html
<video controls autoplay>
  <source src="../Downloads/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
```

Answer (score 0):

its working fine in my system just go to developer tool and check the path of the video is located in src location or parent location.

In my case, both video and HTML are placed in download folder.

```html
<video controls autoplay>
  <source src="../Downloads/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
```

Comment: ya i tried this only audio is playing if path is wrong then i think audio won't play.

Comment: yes, it will always look at path be sure you are given right path or not?

Answer (score -1):

When using a video element, you should consider uploading the video to [youtube](https://youtube.com/upload) or [vimeo](http://vimeo.com/upload) to improve page load times. Then you just copy the embed code provided.